# How to Write API response coming as Byte[] as Pdf file using Javascript or Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress, pdf-generation, npm-package

is there any Write API response coming as Byte[] as Pdf file using Javascript or Typescript

i tried using

```
fs.writeFileSync('FIlename.pdf', apiresponsebody, 'binary')
```

but I am seeing a blank page when I open the saved pdf file
please suggest how to deal with this
At least help me with an example if possible

I even tried npm packages like PDFKit, pdf2html, file-saver etc but all are storing blank pdf file

Comment: Did you connected `multer` to your Express API? Please show the code of the router, Express setup code and how you send a file

Comment: It all depends on what your API is returning,  `Byte[]` is not a Javascript type so it's a bit unclear what format your api response is in.  If you `console.log(apiresponsebody)` what do you see?

Comment: iam getting API response as Byte[] but file is getting saved as blank file with 44kb size